# orgmode - calculate difference between two remote tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I use below code to calculate the difference between two columns from remote tables but the output is all zero!

```
#+name: tbl1
| x |
| 1 | 
| 2 | 
| 3 |

#+name: tbl2
| y |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |

#+name: tbl3
| diff |
|    0 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
#+TBLFM: @2$1..@>$1=remote(tbl1,$1) - remote(tbl2,$1)
```

Comment: refer to orgmode manual https://orgmode.org/org.html, search remote(FOO, @@#$1) to see details

Comment: This seems to indicate that you solved your problem. If so, you should write an answer for it (and  note that you can accept your own answer, thereby indicating to future visitors that the problem is solved). BTW, here's a [more exact link to the documentation](https://orgmode.org/org.html#References).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#+name: tbl1
| x |
| 1 | 
| 2 | 
| 3 |

#+name: tbl2
| y |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |

#+name: tbl3
| diff |
|    0 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
 #+TBLFM: @2$1..@>$1=remote(tbl1,@@#$1) - remote(tbl2,@@#$1)
```